# Autofill formula, but stop short

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, autofill

I have a macro that inserts a number of rows into a spreadsheet, the number of rows stipulated by user input into a dialog box.  What I am trying to achieve is for formula to be autofilled down the respective columns according to the number of rows were inserted by the user.

The current code I have is:

```
Dim iInputRows As Integer
Dim iCount
iInputRows = CInt(InputBox("How many data entry rows required?")) 'message box for user input (interger)

If iInputRows > 1 Then
For iCount = 1 To iInputRows - 1
    Rows(iCount + 13 & ":" & iCount + 13).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove 'insert no. of rows from from first row (row 13) to user input minus 1 (this ensures that the exact no. of rows are inserted from row 13 down)
    Range("D" & iCount + 13).Value = iCount + 1 'column D is used for sequential numbering purposes
Next iCount
End If
```

The formula from which to autofill are `= X13:AR13`.

I am relatively comfortable with the autofill formula, but I am having difficulties in this application to halt the autofill according to the stipulated number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to insert all of the rows at once then use a data series in column D and fill down the formulas in columns X:AR.

```
Dim iInputRows As Long

iInputRows = CInt(InputBox("How many data entry rows required?"))

If iInputRows > 1 Then
    Rows(14).Resize(iInputRows, Columns.Count).EntireRow.Insert _
      Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("D13").Resize(iInputRows + 1, 1).DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, _
      Type:=xlLinear, Step:=1
    Range("X13:AR13").Resize(iInputRows + 1, 21).FillDown
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Jeeped.  The code autofills but I am getting one row more than that stipulated by the user, i.e. 10 rows input = 11 rows inserted.  I have had to change the arguments "(iInputRows + 1,x)" to just "(iInputRows, x)" which sorts it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're doing with the rest of the data but this should work:

```
Sub aaa()
Dim iInputRows As Integer
Dim iCount
iInputRows = CInt(InputBox("How many data entry rows required?"))

If iInputRows > 1 Then
For iCount = 1 To iInputRows - 1
    Rows(iCount + 13 & ":" & iCount + 13).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("D" & iCount + 13).Value = iCount + 1

Next iCount
Range("X13:AR13").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AX13:AR" & iInputRows + 13)
End If
End Sub
```